# Add CalendarView button to Google Maps API V2 - Android

Tags: android, date, view, calendar, picker

I want to implement CalendarView / DatePicker button into my Google Map
How can i do it ?

On click of this button i want a small calendar to open and enable to pick a date from the calendar,when the date is picked i want to execute a function that i wrote.

Thank you !

**The area marked with red doesn't exist right now :

I want this button to open a datePicker

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/390x695q90/633/VyWT4l.jpg

my activity xml right now looks like:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your map view and add button to it like any other layout.
for example you can use this code for your activity layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FC0"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Fixed Footer"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

after that you can use datepicker for showing a dialog to select date.
you can find a solution for it here http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

for calling a function after selecting date you can use **onDateSet** function of datepicker , so call your function inside of **onDateSet**
you can find more informations about it by reading the article that i shared link with you.

Comment: Thank you ! I am new to android, i need to put this XML code inside my activity_maps.xml ?? after the fragment of the map ?

Comment: I don't have your activity_maps.xml code , but yes I think you should put this code inside map fragment, (not after that)

Comment: Thanks Man! i think i'll be ok from here

Comment: yes! thank you. I understood how this whole thing working, the combination of Java code and XML.